# What is the range of random_state in train_test_split

Tags: scikit-learn, train-test-split

I have a dataset with 300 observations, I am doing train_test_split with 75% as train data and 25% as test data.

I got an accuracy of 90% for random_state = 2.
for random_state = 138 , accuracy = 92%
if i increase random state somewhere I will get 96% to 100%.

I wanted to know the range of random_state.

Comment: we set random_state to save the order of spilt and can check those data with another model, random_state don't can improve accuracy, maybe in random_state your data split that your model give better result but you can not conclude that larger random_state can give you a better result.

Comment: Yes, I got the point of using random_state but my question is whether the random_state should be low or high, or can we mention any positive number to it, which means can it be more than 1000? for the same dataset at 228 random_state, I got 94.7% accuracy.

Comment: any int number can be assigned to random_state. yes, 1000 can be use for 228.

Comment: from [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html) : random_stateint, RandomState instance or None, default=None
Controls the shuffling applied to the data before applying the split. Pass an int for reproducible output across multiple function calls.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/glossary.html#term-random_state):

> Integer values must be in the range [0, 2**32 - 1]

In other words, 0 to 4294967295.

There is absolutely no correspondence between the random seed and the performance of your model. Don't treat it like a hyperparameter.

It's a good idea to read [section 10.3 of the User Guide](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/common_pitfalls.html#controlling-randomness). This also explains how you can control the random number generation with more nuance.